# Sending an image from Python to NodeJS + Express via POST

Tags: java, python, node.js, express

On a front end device I have OpenCV running with Python. I then send a computed image to a server for further processing. My problem is I can't decode the image with Express.

I send an image from this front end device thusly (in Python 2.7):

```
import requests

url = "http://10.1.10.194:3000"
files ={'image':open('testimg.jpg','rb')}
r = requests.post(url,files=files)
```

This successfully sends a post command to my Express app, which hears the post request and does the following:

```
app.post('/', function(request, respond) {
console.log(request.headers)
var image = request.body
fs.writeFile('test.jpg', image, function(err){
  if (err) throw err
      console.log('File saved.');
        });
respond.end('thanks');
});
```

I know I'm correctly receiving the picture, as the header correctly lists the filesize, but when I print my image, it's simply a text file [Object object].

Output of the Express app is here:

```
{ host: '10.1.10.194:3000',
  'content-length': '14551',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  accept: '*/*',
  'user-agent': 'python-requests/2.9.1',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=e664d9584c484962bfe4d1577bd4d91b' }
POST / 200 15.754 ms - -
File saved.
```

My Express app is successfully loading body-parser, but I can't seem to figure out how to get my raw data out of the request.body. Any advice is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using Multer module ?

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest: './uploads/'});

app.post('/', upload.single('file'), function(request, respond) {
    if(request.file) console.log(request.file);
}
```

https://github.com/expressjs/multer

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you very much Jibeee.A note to other beginners like me, I had to match my python field names (i.e., upload.single('file') to say upload.single('image') ). The file saved in the uploads directory as indicated with the multer call at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for post data to be extracted.

```
            if (request.method == 'POST') {
                var body = '';
                request.on('data',function(data) { body += data; });
                request.on('end', function(data) {
                 fs.writeFile('test.jpg', body, function(err){ ... })

            });
```